# Error setting up JNDI DataSource

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, jndi

I'm starting in Java. I'm following a tutorial to setting up a JNDI DataSource using Tomcat, but I'm not able to achieve it. I always get the same error, error 500. The exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException.

The error is:

```
HTTP Status 500 - 

type Exception report

message 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    demo.DatasourceDemo.doGet(DatasourceDemo.java:60)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.15 logs.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
```

My web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.4">
  <description>MySQL Test App</description>
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TestDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

My Context.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->

    <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>

</Context>
```

My servlet looks like:

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DatasourceDemo
 */
@WebServlet("/DatasourceDemo")
public class DatasourceDemo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private DataSource ds;   
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DatasourceDemo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Servlet#init(ServletConfig)
     */
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();

            Context env = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:com/env");

            ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
            out.println("Connection error");
            return;
        }

        out.println("Finally connected");

        /*try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

I'm using Eclipse Luna.
Can anyone help me please?
Any help is much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: For a start, make sure the JNDI path is `comp/env`, *NOT* `com/env`.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, but now I get a different exception, this is the message: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: Maybe provide more data. Better yet, ask it in a new question, as it seems to be a different problem.

Comment: As you have suggested, I have made a new question (Servlet execution threw an exception org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter). Thanks once again